# Enable detail logging for iis inside a docker container

Tags: .net, docker, iis

I have a legacy .net web application that I am running inside a docker container based off the microsoft/iis image. If I browse to the application I get a 
`500 - Internal server error`

I did some googling and it turns out that since I am now seen by the server as a remote client and not on the same machine, it will no longer serve me the detailed error messages directly. Apparently the solution to this is to turn off custom errors like so:

```
<customErrors mode="Off"/>
```

I tried this, but it has no effect.

Does anyone know how to configure iis/my app to allow me to see the detailed errors?

Comment: have you tried the `docker logs -f containerName` ? to see the logs provided

Comment: @Edwin No output, The ENTRYPOINT for the microsoft/iis container is ServiceMonitor.exe. It doesn't realy log anything.

Comment: sorry, I'm not familiar with the docker container for microsoft, but worth trying.

Comment: Did you figure out a way?

Answer (score -1):

I think this pull request is what you are looking for:

https://github.com/Microsoft/IIS.ServiceMonitor/pull/13

The change reads events and writes to stdout.

Comment: The essential parts of the answer are "The (new) change reads events and writes to stdout." Implied: you will need this update; it's not as if anyone would likely implement the fix independently. This link is not to a description of *a* fix; it is to *the* fix. Bug report links, for fixes in particular will very rarely change.

Comment: Only way to include the essential parts of the fix here is to include that patch... that's silly... if the pull request is gone then the pull is complete and this question does not need to be asked. js